# DefaultListModel Error

Tags: java

I am trying to fill jList but "NullPointerException" is occurring in my code please help,
my code is following

```
private void fillChemList() {
    List<Test> chemList = null;

    chemList = lab.viewChemList(); //this is working correctly

    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) chem.getModel();   //Here is ERROR


    for(int i = 0; i < chemList.size(); i++)
    {
        model.addElement(chemList.get(i).getName());   
    }

}
```

Comment: You have not given us enough information to look into the issue. Kindly post the full stacktrace, the relevant method definitions, and at least post a compilable code.

Comment: @RohitJain i have a List "chemList" which have two attributes one is "Name" and second is "normalvalue" Now i want to show list of names in my GUI frame, in GUI frame class i call this method "fillChemList()" which need to fill jList (at GUI) with names of chemList.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use: `chemList.getModel()`  instead of  `chem.getModel();`